# Boolean not changing value

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def shoot(self, limb):
    if not limb:
        pass
    else:
        limb = False    


print Joe.body.head #prints out true
Bob.gun.shoot(Joe.body.head) # should print out false
print Joe.body.head #prints out true (???)
```

I'm new to Python and am making a game as part of the LPTHW. My shoot function is supposed to disable a limb by setting it to false, but it doesn't edit the boolean at all. This might seem a bit redundant considering that I can set the boolean directly, but the shoot function will calculate a lot more than just changing a boolean. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a solution, but just a suggestion, your if/else could be reduced to `if limb: limb = False`

Comment: @Levon or even `lambda L: not L`

Comment: That would give you `True` if `L` was initially `False`. Shooting an already-shot limb doesn't suddenly make it regenerate, now does it?

Answer (score 7):

Python passes its object references by value, so by doing `limb = False` you're assigning a new object reference with the value `False` to the parameter `limb`, not modifying the object originally held by the parameter. (Well, technically it's not a "new" reference, as I believe `True`, `False`, and `None` are all singletons in Python.)

Here's something that would work, however.

```
def shoot(self, other, limbstr):
    try:
        if getattr(other, limbstr):     # Levon's suggestion was a good one
            setattr(other, limbstr, False)
    except AttributeError:
        pass   # If the other doesn't have the specified attribute for whatever reason, then no need to do anything as the bullet will just pass by

Bob.gun.shoot(Joe.body, 'head')
```

Comment: Much cleaner solution than I was thinking of (a series of if/elif). I like it.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a minor optimization of JAB's answer, if you don't need to differentiate between limbs that don't exist and limbs that have been previously shot.

```
def shoot(self, other, limbstr):
    if getattr(other, limbstr, False):
        setattr(other, limbstr, False)
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot that `getattr()` allowed for a default result. That would indeed be a bit more efficient than letting an exception be raised when `other` doesn't have the attribute specified by `limbstr`.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, if `limb` has the value `False` then it enters the then branch that does nothing (`not False`) and the value stays `False`. If `limb` is `True` then `not True` is `False` and the `else` branch is activated. This way, `limb` is assigned `False`. No way to get `True` in this piece of code.

The `limb` is the reference to the `False`. Even if the automatically dereferenced value of the `limb` were `True`, the original variable passed to the function would still refer to the original `True` object. The reason is that the boolean value is immutable. Any assignment to the `limb` only changes the value of the reference. But the outer reference is then independent on the inner reference.

If you want to get the value out of the function, the easiest way is to return it. Or you have to pass the reference to the object that is mutable.

There is also bad design of the `shoot()` method. It gets the boolean value assuming that it is a new value of the limb. However, the value of the `head` is passed. Total confusion never produces expected result. The `Joe.body.head` is or `True` or `False` passed to `Bob.gun.shoot()`. What the `gun.shoot()` expects to get?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was why assigning to the local parameter name did not affect the value of the object used as the argument for that parameter.

Comment: Updated to make it consumable by the beginner.